# Какие преимущетсва и недостатки есть при упаковывания веб-приложения как jar или war файла

Tags: java, spring, jar, war

Какие преимущества и недостатки есть у каждого способа ?

1. Способ использовать модуль spring boot, который имеет встроенную tomcat веб-сервер, и запуск приложение происходит просто за счет запуска jar файла.
2. Способ это собирать war файл и класть в папочку webapps собранный war файл, где tomcat его развернет и запустит.

Второй способ выглядит сложнее, может быть есть какие-то преимущества откладки? Или какие-то уникальные настройки, что второй способ ещё живет?

Comment: Ответ есть в гугле. Я проверил.

Comment: @dmtr  Можно ссылочку?

Comment: Посмотрел описение данного вопроса на [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jar-war-packaging).

И не нашёл ни одного преимущества war архива.

Так же нашёл более менее схожий вопрос на англоязычном [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165428/differences-between-jar-and-war-in-spring-boot).

Там говорится, если хотите развернуть приложение на уже существующем боевом сервере, то используйте war. Хотя по идее можно  вообще отказаться от локально установленного tomcat.

Так же преимуществом запуска через jar является то, что можно использовать Intellij idea community.